# how to print a javascript object with nested properties using developer tools without the nested properties pointing to the wrong references

Tags: javascript, console

Example:

```
var o = {
a: 12,
gg: {
    mm: {
        a: 15
    }
}
}
console.log(o, _.copy(o))
o.gg.mm.a = 44
```

in this case, in the developer tools, it would print "o" twice and the value of o.gg.mm.a would be different

In the first one, the value is 44

In the second one, the value is 15 -- thanks to the jquery copy function or underscore clone function

When printing Backbone models which are much more complex, it is constantly printing the object pointing to the wrong reference i.e 44 instead of 15 (regardless if clone/copy is used)

There are several options to display these properties (even with Backbone models) but they are all terrible:

- use a wrapper with known limitations i.e clone/copy/extend  to handle nested properties
- copy/clone/extend specific properties to get to the nested objects i.e console.log(_.copy(o.gg.mm))
- using console.log on the values directly i.e console.log(o.gg.mm.a) to get the right value
- launch the debugger and inspect the values

Is there something simpler? I want to view the object and its properties without the console.log deceiving me with a misread

Comment: If you don't have too much going on in the object and don't need to it be live, you could always serialise to string (by JSON or a function that loops over and recurses own properties, using toString)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the console is lazily evaluated – that is to say that values for the object's properties are only fetched after you click to view the object.

If you're using Chrome you might want to consider setting a breakpoint which will halt code execution so you can view the object before it's modified.

More info on breakpoints can be found here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints